# How to solve error in mysql when I create table

Tags: mysql, sql

When I create a table using the following statement, I get an error.

```sql
CREATE TABLE HOTEL(ROOM_NUMBER, check_in_date, check_out_date)
```

Error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near ', check_in_date, check_out_date)' at line 1

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: add the query to the post, but at least you missing data type [Creating tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-tables.html)

Comment: where is the query ?

Comment: Titles should summarise your question, but the body of the question should actually contain a question with all details. I have edited the question so the actual question (and your code) is in the body.

Answer (score 1):

you must have to define datatype like this:

```
CREATE TABLE HOTEL(
    ROOM_NUMBER int,
    check_in_date datetime,
    check_out_date datetime
);
```

[source](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp)